# How to read ID from XSOM XSElementDecl

Tags: parsing, xsd, xsom

veI am using XSOM in Java to parse an XSD.  It's working really well but there's one piece of information from an element that I just can't seem to get hold of - namely the "id" attribute.
One of my elements looks like this :-

```
<xsd:element name="ACCOUNTTITLE1" minOccurs="0" id="ACCOUNT.TITLE.1" nillable="true">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>ACCOUNT.TITLE.1</xsd:documentation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <hfp:hasProperty name="fielddatatype" value=""/>
            <hfp:hasProperty name="fieldname" value="ACCOUNT.TITLE.1"/>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="35"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

Here I am trying to retrieve the "ACCOUNT.TITLE.1" text stored in the "id" part of the xsd:element.
Any ideas ?

A safe alternative would also to retrieve it from the "xsd:appinfo" section "fieldname" property.  However, I can't see how to get hold of that either!

Any help appreciated.

Sarah